# get command line argument verbatim in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to get user command exactly the way they typed. The only allowed difference is `'` can come in place of `"` and vice versa.

For example, if the user typed.

```
node test.js git commit -m "first message"
```

I want to log either of following on console.

```
You typed: git commit -m 'first message' //line A
You typed: git commit -m "first message" //line B
```

But there is not acceptable:

```
You typed: "git" "commit" "-m" "first message" //line C
You typed: 'git' 'commit' '-m' 'first message' // line D
```

As you can see above, quotes can be in different than the user provided (`'` can replace `"` and vice versa like in line B) but they can't be misplaced (like in line C and D). Hope this is clear.

Edit:
Edited the whole question to avoid confusion.

Comment: The quotes are interpreted by the shell prior to being handed to node, so without explicit escaping and quoting the entire command (e.g. `"git commit -m \"first message\""`) you might not be able to do what you want.

Comment: Joe...I made an edit. Can you pls tell me if that is possible?

Comment: the edit is not clear, please specify exactly what you want not the unacceptable results

Comment: I edited the question. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but assuming that you just want to log the arguments you are receiving you can do it like this:

```
let args = [];
// Get program arguments
process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
if (index > 1)
    args.push(val);
});
let command = args.join(" ");
console.log("You typed: ", command);
```

But note that you **will lose the quotes** when printing the output, as said by @Joe inthe comments, the shell scapes them before passing them to node